# variable 'min' in date input type of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I want a JavaScript that restricts user to enter a date which is minimum 5 days after today date .I've written js for getting todays date but i can't figure out how to change 'min' value dynamically.Here,I've entered constant value for min as 2016-02-14.how to make this as variable ?

```
<input type='date' id='d1' name='d1' min="2016-02-14">
<script type="text/javascript">
var d1 = new Date();
var y1= d1.getFullYear();
var m1 = d1.getMonth()+1;
if(m1<10)
  m1="0"+m1;
var dt1 = d1.getDate();
if(dt1<10)
  dt1 = "0"+dt1;
var d2 = y1+"-"+m1+"-"+dt1;
document.getElementById('d1').value=d2;
</script>
```

Comment: Try this: document.getElementsByID("d1").setAttribute("min", yourdate);

Comment: yeh,tat worked perfectly !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this - not sure it will work in all browsers though - firefox and IE may not support min and max values for date / time inputs. Probably better to use a datetime or timestamp and use it as a number (which would be easy to set as a min value) and modify the input .

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Date</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type='date' id='d1' name='d1' min="">
    </form>
<script>
    var d1 = new Date();
        var y1= d1.getFullYear();
        var m1 = d1.getMonth()+1;
            if(m1<10){ m1="0"+m1};
        var dt1 = d1.getDate();
            if(dt1<10){dt1 = "0"+dt1};
        var d2 = y1+"-"+m1+"-"+dt1;
    document.getElementById('d1').value=d2;


    var future = new Date();
future.setDate(future.getDate() + 5);
 var futureYear= future.getFullYear();
    var futureMonth = future.getMonth()+1;
        if(futureMonth<10){futureMonth="0"+futureMonth};
    var futureDay = future.getDate();
        if(futureDay<10){futureDay = "0"+futureDay};
    var futureDate = futureYear+"-"+futureMonth+"-"+futureDay;
    document.getElementById('d1').setAttribute("min", futureDate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if date is between 26-30... will adding +5 work for date variable without any logical error ?

Comment: yes it shouldl. I just experimented with the dates in the code - adding 15 days made the first available date the 29th of this month (it's a leap year) and then I changed it to adding 16 and it made the first available date the first of next month (01/03/2016). Gotta love javascript!

Comment: glad to help. Happy coding -just  remember about the cross browser issue though. It may not give the desired result for all peoples.